# IonAuth groups - not returning correct value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, ion-auth

so I just started to use Ion_Auth lib for my CI applications and anyway I am having a bit of trouble with the results I get when using the library function `in_group`. Everything worked fine until I manually edited the default admin account and deleted it from the members group; yet if I do a check with `in_group` I am constantly getting returned that admin is a member of both groups.

So the following code returns both if statements as true, although admin is only in the admin user group...

`if ($this->ion_auth->in_group('admin')) echo 1;`

`if ($this->ion_auth->in_group('members')) echo 2;`

I've already tried logging out, clearing my cookies and cache but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem is that IonAuth cached that info, so when editing the db directly you also have to make a corresponding call
`$this->ion_auth->remove_from_group(1,2)`